# What does Black Ops 2 season pass include?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

Does it come with both revolution and uprising map packs?  Or do I have to purchase each season pass separately?

Are revolution maps still available?  I know nuketown is in the regular multiplayer rotation, what about the other 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[THIS](http://www.callofduty.com/blackops2/dlc/seasonpass) comes from the official black ops 2 site :

> Buy the Call of Duty®: Black Ops 2 DLC Season Pass and get all four
>   epic DLC Map Packs**, including the Revolution DLC Map Pack, for the
>   discounted price of $49.99*, plus an exclusive in-game calling card
>   and access to the Nuketown Zombies bonus map.

So you can say that when your purchasing the season pass you get ALL of the upcoming DLC maps.

Comment: Good deal, after watching the replacements promo, I have to get this :)

Comment: yep it is way cheaper that purchasing every part on its own even if you only think you're gonna buy 1.

Answer (score 0):

It makes all DLC free if you're on XBox 360 but on the PS3 it's just a discount for all DLC for 25% off.

Answer (score 0):

Season Pass is a one time purchase for all of the newly released content for BOII for the xbox 360. Of which includes maps, zombies, etc. I do not know about the Playstation though. So instead of paying for the maps each time they come out you get to buy them all at once even the future DLCs for a total cheaper price than it would have been for buying them all separately.

Answer (score 0):

My friend got it and it has Vengance pack, Uprising pack, Revoloution pack, die rise, Mob of the dead, Turned and  Buried

Answer (score 0):

It includes all DLC as in map packs and weapons for the X-Box 360.  It does NOT include weapon skins.  So all of the Multiplayer and Zombie maps are included as well as any new/bonus weapons. I don't know about any other game console.